# How to selectively replace characters in a string?

Tags: python

How would I replace characters in a string for certain indices in Python?

For example, I have `version = "00.00.00"` and need to change each of the 0s to a different value, say 3, to look like `"33.33.33"`. Also, would this be possible if I had a variable storing this value. If I have `vnumber = "3"`, would I be able to get the same output by using the variable? I'm sure `replace()` is a good function to use for this, but I'm not sure about syntax.

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
“Show me how to solve this coding problem” is not a Stack Overflow issue.  We expect you to make an honest attempt, and *then* ask a *specific* question about your algorithm or technique.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing documentation and tutorials.
"I'm not sure about syntax" simply means that you do not yet have a question to post: you are responsible to look up the syntax and examples.

Comment: "I'm sure replace() is a good function to use for this, but I'm not sure about syntax." Well, what happened when you tried reading its documentation?

Comment: This is not the place to ask about the basics of a language. Those are for the various tutorials out there. You are expected to show some effort. Do your research.

Comment: What part of the [`str.replace()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) method's documentation are you having difficulty understanding?

Answer (score 2):

From an interactive session, you could type:

```
>>> help(str.replace)
```

But to answer the question most directly:

```py
vnumber = '3'
newversion = version.replace('0', vnumber)
```

Is probably what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Your guess about [`str.replace`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) was right. It takes to arguments, the first is the string to be found in the original string, and the second is the string to replace the found occurrences of the first argument with. Code could be like this:

```py
vnumber = "3"
version = "00.00.00"

newversion = version.replace("0", vnumber)

print(newversion)
```